# Publish an npm package that requires CSS from node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

A React component I'm trying to publish to npm requires a CSS stylesheet from one of my project's dependencies in `node_modules`. Basically, my `index.js` file (which exposes my component to the outside-world) looks like this:

```
import Gallery from './containers/GalleryContainer';
require('../../node_modules/jscrollpane/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css');
export default Gallery;
```

This works within my webpack-powered dev environment because webpack picks up the CSS file and injects it into the DOM (using css-loader and style-loader), but if I'm not sure how to package this up for distribution. I want to publish the package as ES5 and want users to be able to use it within an ES6 context (with webpack/browserify) or directly in the browser.

So far, I transpile my ES6 code into ES5 with Babel into my `lib` folder on `prepublish`. That takes care of the javascript, but not the CSS that it requires.

Do I have to instruct users of my library to link the CSS manually or is there a way for that require statement to be portable?

Comment: Are you looking to add a peer dependency to your npm package ?https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Babel is the part here, so much as changing your `require` to an `import`. You should be able to do something like:

```js
import '../../node_modules/jscrollpane/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css';
```

Then you have to make sure that you have the proper webpack `rules` in place for handling your css. In our webpack process, we actually `import` a SASS file, in our entry point, that includes multiple `@import` (SASS code) declarations for node_modules css files, and use a `rule` that handles the SASS compilation to a separate css file, but I've been lead to believe the process is basically identical with straight css files, with the proper `rules` and loaders. Look at the webpack docs for the `css-loader` and the `style-loader` for more information.

Also remember that, if any of those stylesheets reference image or font file, you will want loaders to handle extracting those assets as well.